# Tool/Library to convert SVG paths cuves from quadratic to cubic

Tags: svg

As you guys probably know, in SVGs you can represent curves as either [quadratic](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-curves/quadratic-curve.html) or [cubic](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-curves/cubic-curve.html) (bezier) curves.

I ran into an [issue](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/329) using a project that doesn't work with bezier curves. I am thinking of solving this problem by converting SVGs that use quadratic curves to use cubic ones.

Is there an existing library, framework, tool to do this? Maybe a python script? I feel like I'm not the first one to run into this issue.

Comment: You may find this useful: [Quadratic to cubic Bézier in SVG](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/post/quadratic-to-cubic-b-zier-in-svg)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, [cairosvg](https://cairosvg.org/) can do that. Invocation is something like this:

```
cairosvg input.svg -f svg -o output.svg
```